# How do you call multiple keys from an object in one variable

Tags: javascript, variables

This is the code

```
const restaurant = {
    name: 'Ichiran Ramen',
    address: `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1} Johnson Ave`,
    city: 'Brooklyn',
    state: 'NY',
    zipcode: '11206',
```

I want to create a variable "fullAddress" which should point to a string using the information from `restaurant`
`fullAdress` should have address city state and zipcode.

my approach is

```
let fullAddress = restaurant.address;
fullAddress += restaurant.city;
fullAddress += restaurant.state;
fullAddress += restaurant.zipcode;
```

but this seems odd to me and lengthy and it is not having spaces in between.

any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenate multiple object property values into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38754054/concatenate-multiple-object-property-values-into-one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is not overly verbose and it is defensibly clear to read, however you aren't concatenating a comma and space in between the address components. To get the correct result using your approach:

```js
let fullAddress = restaurant.address;
fullAddress += ', ';
fullAddress += restaurant.city;
fullAddress += ', ';
fullAddress += restaurant.state;
fullAddress += ', ';
fullAddress += restaurant.zipcode;
```

However, if you would like a more succinct approach, and assuming you are working in a modern (ES6) environment, you can use template literals for this.

For example, if you wanted the final string to be `123 Johnson Ave, Brooklyn, NY, 11206`

You would write this as:

```js
const fullAddress = `${restaurant.address}, ${restaurant.city}, ${restaurant.state}, ${restaurant.zipcode}`;
```

Note that the syntax for template literals uses backticks, not normal quotes.

[More information about template literals on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Answer (score 3):

You can define a getter property

```js
const restaurant = {
    name: 'Ichiran Ramen',
    address: `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1} Johnson Ave`,
    city: 'Brooklyn',
    state: 'NY',
    zipcode: '11206',
    get fullAddress() {
      const { address, city, state, zipcode } = this;
      return `${address} ${city} ${state} ${zipcode}`;
    }
}

console.log(restaurant.fullAddress);
```

Comment: Please add your answer to the identified duplicate question rather than answering this one.

Comment: I think the 2 questions are sligtly different. The answer you identified regards objects modification, this one is about getting values.